# Custom angular datepicker values

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible to custom [Angular Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) values in order to show yearly weeks intead of month days  ?

this way :

W1  W2  W3 ..

W5  W6 W7  ..

...... W52

Comment: it seems like you're sort of fighting the framework here. What defines W1 vs W52? I'd recommend making a reusable custom component using something like mat-select.

Comment: Well, Angular Material date picker doesn't have this option. but you can create a custom component to handle that  and I  recommend to you use moment library to do you conversions it is easy to get weeks, months, years etc.

Comment: W1, W2 .. ect is a static array. I think I was not clear. I would make a yearly weeks matrix and be able to select them

Comment: @AbelValdez , how can I substitut displayed month days with 52 year weeks ?